# Sum only specified columns in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services

I need to sum the row values except the first one. It would be pretty easy, but the first column in a row may be null, so there is no value there. Using First() function returns first column that has value. So it can be 3rd visible in a row.

Is there any way to achieve this effect? (Summing all columns except first)

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with this expression

```
=Sum(Fields!yourcolumn.Value) - IIF(ISNOTHING(FIRST(Fields!yourcolumn.Value)),0,FIRST(Fields!yourcolumn.Value))
```

Comment: It returns strange values, as First is not returning the first column, but first not empty.

Comment: In my test case it worked for me. Please could you share your expression and some sample data. we can look at the issue.